# Problem with paging on Multisite

Tags: multisite, pagination

I am using this loop too paginate, but it doesn't work.

I have tried to set `$wp_query` `$paged` as `global` to but it didn´t help.

I got the link to previous page, but then i click on the link I get a page that does not exist. ( page/2/ )

First I used the_query as variable instead of $wp_query, but then there will be no link at all.

I am using a category template that using this loop-page.

I am using it on a multisite on blog3.

The code you can see below.

```
<section class="pressLoop">

<?php 
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
// $page = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

$args = array('category_name' => 'pressmeddelande', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged);

// The Query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // 'cat=4&paged=' . $paged

// The Loop
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article class="row loop" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 loopArticleImage">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); }  ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-9 loopArticleContent" >
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Läs mer om <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="loopSmall"><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>">Publicerat <?php the_time('j F, Y') ?></time>. <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><a class="comment" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments"><?php comments_number('0 Kommentarer', '1 Kommentar', '% Kommentarer'); ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>
                </header>
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
                <footer>
                    <div style="float:right;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="Läs mer om <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Läs mer if  »</a></div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </article>
<?php   }
} else {
    // no posts found
} ?>

<nav class="paging">
    <div class="prev">
        <?php
            // usage with max_num_pages
            next_posts_link( '&laquo; Tidigare pressmeddelande' ); // $the_query->max_num_pages
        ?>  
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <?php
            previous_posts_link( 'Senare pressmeddelande &raquo;' );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>

   <?php
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>


</section>
```

Kind Regards,
Mats Gustavsson

Comment: You shouldn't set your new WP_Query to the $wp_query variable.  Also you should really just use a category template and instead of doing a new WP_Query add a pre_get_posts filter.

Comment: First I used the_query as variable instead of $wp_query, but then there will be no link at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the category archive template you do not need to create a new WP_Query instance.  Just filter the main query using `pre_get_posts()`.

Put this in functions php or a plugin:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', wp_se_pre_get_posts' );
function wp_se_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query || ! is_category( 'pressmeddelande' )
        return $query;

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );

}
```